Odd graphics driver issue on Dell Precision 7540 running Kubuntu 24.04
Recently after a windows game I was playing through proton crashed on me something seems to have broken with my graphics driver. After this crash my laptop only boots using the safe mode grub option or if I disable switchable graphics in the bios. When I use the first option some features stop working (like the brightness settings for example), and with the second I get odd UI scaling.
I am running Kubuntu 24.04 on a Dell Precision 7540 with an Nvidia Quadro T2000 GPU. My kernel version is 6.8.0-31-generic​. Sorry about not posting more details, but I am still rather noob-ish at linux.

When you boot in safe mode you are not loading the installed driver, therefore that is not a real issue it is working as it should.

I know that, the issue is that outside of safe mode it does not boot when switchable graphics are on in the bios. And when I disable them, I get really weird scaling issues with the KDE UI.
My guess is something broke with the driver, but I can't figure out what.

I would suggest try and leave it off in the BIOS and see if there is a new or better driver you can install in the OS.
